# how to set path in terminal on ubuntu for java?

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal

I have recently installed ubuntu and want to start compiling programs in the terminal. What is the command to set the path for java in ubuntu terminal? I tried "cd path" but it did not work. Could anyone please tell me the right command?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Follow the steps here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all if you have not installed java you need to execute the command

$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

if it does not work then first execute

$ sudo apt-get update

and the execute the above command

and the do

$ sudo vi /etc/profile

and at the last line of the file add
JAVA_HOME={path to java home}
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

and do $ . /etc/profile

and now you are good to go
to see the effect type java -version

Comment: you can vote my answer up so that it will be easy for others to find the answer for the same question

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can avoid set the path by following phase:

First you can add ppa:

> $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

Then update:

> $ sudo apt-get update

Then install it:

> $ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

Finally, check it using the following command:

> $ java -version

Result:

> java version "1.8.0_05"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

Try export command.

Check in which location jdk is installed ( in ubuntu, its mostly in /usr/java/(javaVersion))

update the path variable using export:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/(javaVersion)/bin
```